# Can't use simple Rust library in main.rs or examples

Tags: rust

This is my Rust project structure:

```
zlmediakit_rust/examples
zlmediakit_rust/src
zlmediakit_rust/src/interface/lots_of_files_and_mod_rs
zlmediakit_rust/src/zl_media/lots_of_files_and_mod_rs
zlmediakit_rust/src/main.rs
zlmediakit_rust/Cargo.toml
```

In `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "zlmediakit_rust"
version = "0.1.0"
```

In `main.rs` I have:

```
use zlmediakit_rust::zl_media;

fn main() {
    println!("hello world");
}
```

but it says it can't find any `zlmediakit_rust`. Also tried adding an example that uses `zlmediakit_rust` or declares it as an extern crate, won't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `mod zl_media; use crate::zl_media`

Comment: @Shepmaster and what about for examples?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs in that case you `use zlmediakit_rust::zl_media`, as long as the `mod zl_media` in `main.rs` is a `pub mod zl_media`.

Comment: @OptimisticPeach it isn't working on my case. `pub mod zl_media;
pub mod interface;` in `main.rs`. Anything more needed?

Comment: @OptimisticPeach for me what worked was to put them in lib.rs and use `use zlmediakit_rust::zl_media::zl_media::ZLMedia;`

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs if you've got something along the lines of `use crate_name::module::module::whatever`, then that's pointing to you declaring another mod inside of the new file. `zl_media.rs` should contain the contents of the module; `pub mod zl_media` in `main.rs` already declares a new module. (IE, **do not** surround the contents of `zl_media.rs` with `mod zl_media { /** **/ }`)